# how to set Bootstrap slider value

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-slider

I use bootstrap slider and looking for a way to set a value of the handle from 
an other variable , I found this method, but didn't work with me..
data-slider-value is the attribute that contains the value
html

```
<input id="gravite" name="gravite" type="text"
              data-provide="slider"
              data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]"
              data-slider-ticks-labels='["Faible", "Moyenne", "Urgent"]'
              data-slider-min="1"
              data-slider-max="3"
              data-slider-step="1"
                data-slider-value=""
              data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
```

javascript

```
var val=$(this).attr('gravite');
 $("#gravite").slider('setValue',val);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data-provide="slider"
```

allows not to write any javascript code. The only thing is that you need to put the dependency on javascipt for bootstrap-slider (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/6.1.7/bootstrap-slider.min.js) in the end of your html (for example, just before ).
Also note that it must be version 6.1.7 or higher!